# Magento2 Custom theme register but does read layout & template files

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I have create a custom theme and it has been register but it does not read layout & Templates.

**File location:**
*app/design/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/composer.json*

```
{
    "name": "magento/theme-frontend-Customtheme",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

*registration.php*

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Amit/Customtheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

*And: theme.xml*

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Amit Customtheme</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
</theme>
```

And then try to add css/js  files from *app/design/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/style.css" />
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <css src="css/responsive.css" />
        <css src="css/my-account.css" />
        <css src="css/home-slider.css" />
        <css src="css/easy-responsive-tabs.css" />
        <css src="css/login.css" />
        <css src="css/login-signup.css" />
        <css src="css/mega-menu.css" />
        <css src="css/cart-dropdown.css" />
        <css src="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <css src="css/hover.css" />
        <css src="css/animate.css" />
        <css src="css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <css src="css/settings.css" />
        <css src="css/strocke-gap-icons-style.css" />
        <css src="css/thank_you.css" />

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <script src="js/easy-responsive-tabs.js"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"/>


    </head>
</page>
```

but this **layout files does  not read** because of when i  have check **page  view source**  then  not see  css/js files which are default_head_blocks.xml.  Only see blank  theme's css /js file

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/css/styles-l.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/css/print.css" />
<link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<link  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
            </head>
```

***Why it does not read layout/ template files from custom theme.What i am going wrong at Theme configuration?***

Comment: Did you run bin/magento setup:upgrade, enabled the theme from admin and deployed the content?

Comment: yes , i  have already done both  command

Comment: Is the template visible in your admin?

Comment: I have already set a that Amit/Customtheme theme at admin.You see `ttp://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Amit/Customtheme/en_US ..` called that means theme is registered

Comment: change `"name": "magento/theme-frontend-Customtheme",` to `"name": "magento/theme-frontend-blank",` this issue i only found

Comment: all file css, js  you want add just in Amit/Customtheme/Web/...

Comment: yes ... you  are right. But does not only problem.Problem is  the theme's any layout and template file does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check current store scope? Do you create new store for custom theme 

Flush cache and re-deploy static files. I already test in magento 2 version 2.0.4 developer mode . My custom theme loaded successful

From backend make sure magento loaded your theme in tab Content\Design\Themes
If it loaded check your current store that your theme setup
[image]